# Exporting x,y coordinates as latitude,longitude in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, convert, latitude-longitude, xy

I have a shapefile and I loaded it into QGIS using *'Add vector layer'*.
After that, I can see points in different positions.

I open the Attribute table and I can see columns `"X"` and `"Y"` with values such as (`151449.965057`, `204642.790761`). Now I want to convert them to latitude and longitude. How can I do that?

Therefore, I use the option *'Save as'* to export the data to CSV format using the CRS WGS 84.

However, nothing changes in the CSV file (`"X"` and `"Y"` stay the same as the original data).

[image: example]

I read and tried several suggestions from this forum without help, e.g., [Converting x,y coordinates to longitude,latitude using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64535/converting-x-y-coordinates-to-longitude-latitude-using-qgis).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before exporting there are several more steps have to be applied.

**Step 1.** Create two additional fields, i.e. `"lat"` and `"long"` via the [image: calc] [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator)

**Step 2.** Apply the following expressions for `"lat"` and `"long"` respectively

For `"lat"` :

```
x(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:31370'))
```

For `"long"` :

```
y(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:31370'))
```

or alternatively, you can already use your `"X"` and `"Y"` fields with

For `"lat"` :

```
transform("X", 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:31370')
```

For `"long"` :

```
transform("Y", 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:31370')
```

Additionally, I may refer you to this article: [Adding x,y coordinates to Attribute table in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/359940/172348)

Answer (score 1):

This is the corresponding programming solution (Python).

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyproj import Proj, transform

data = pd.read_csv('org_canyon_features.csv')

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:31370')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')

def f(x):
    return transform(inProj, outProj, x['X'], x['Y'])

coordinates = data.apply(lambda x: f(x), result_type='expand', axis=1)
data = pd.concat([data, coordinates], axis=1)

data.to_csv('converted_canyon_features.csv', index=None)
```