# QGIS 3x capturing coordinates for multitude of objects at once

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I would like to ask about the possibility of capturing coordinates for more than 1 object in QGIS.

I used to use the coordinate capture plugin, but what is the problem there I have to collect coordinates one by one.

Is there any way to collect coordinates i.e. for all points from the given layer and export them to excel? Following their names or different features from data attribute table?

[image]

I will by more than happy if someone clarifies it for me.

UPDATE:

Following the answer below, I tried to run the $x expression, but it returns NULL.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "capturing" and what you're doing with the coordinates afterwards.

Comment: Capturing - implicitly - gathering the coordinates, as you do with coordinate capture plugin. I need them as a list in Excel. There are about 30-40 of them from each layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `NULL` while using `$x` or `$y` because your geometry is probably either Polylines or Polygons.

So, I will suggest employing this expression to capture coordinates for a multitude of objects at once

```py
map_to_json(
    map(
        'x', array_to_string(array_foreach(generate_series(1, num_points($geometry)), x(point_n($geometry, @element)))),
        'y', array_to_string(array_foreach(generate_series(1, num_points($geometry)), y(point_n($geometry, @element))))
     )
)
```

So, the result will look as following

```
{"x":"5395496.429117461,5395494.155999963,5395489.773418307","y":"5659901.713053187,5659897.333999608,5659899.601836967"}
{"x":"5396759.156386755,5396761.318999965,5396764.051999965,5396762.000375618,5396760.367999964,5396755.841312531","y":"5660769.610787445,5660770.32399961,5660769.08599961,5660764.5589490365,5660760.95699961,5660763.009167434"}
{"x":"5397230.945016465,5397230.575999966,5397225.642692687","y":"5660956.466597664,5660951.539999611,5660951.8752865605"}
...
```

There is also a possibility of using this expression with a different formatting

```py
array_to_string(
               array_foreach(generate_series(1, num_points($geometry)),
                             'Point_'  || @element || ': (' || x(point_n($geometry, @element))|| ', ' || y(point_n($geometry, @element)) || ')'
                )
)
```

That will lead to this

```
Point_1: (5395496.429117461, 5659901.713053187),Point_2: (5395494.155999963, 5659897.333999608),Point_3: (5395489.773418307, 5659899.601836967)
Point_1: (5396759.156386755, 5660769.610787445),Point_2: (5396761.318999965, 5660770.32399961),Point_3: (5396764.051999965, 5660769.08599961),Point_4: (5396762.000375618, 5660764.5589490365),Point_5: (5396760.367999964, 5660760.95699961),Point_6: (5396755.841312531, 5660763.009167434)
Point_1: (5397230.945016465, 5660956.466597664),Point_2: (5397230.575999966, 5660951.539999611),Point_3: (5397225.642692687, 5660951.8752865605)
...
```

Both cases are approachable in the "Field Calculator" via creating a new text(string) field and using those expressions in Expression Dialog.

[image: result]

*Note:* it shall do the work for all geometry types

Comment: The expression works, but how to use it really. I plotted it into my data attribute table, where is the "e" - expression symbol and I saw your result at the very bottom like you wrote (points with coordinates) but I couldn't plot them into my data attribute table column. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Simply create a new a new text(string) field and use those expressions there

Comment: Hi,

Is that the way that I should use?

https://imgur.com/gallery/fdp1atX

It doesn't provide any result. Where should I roughly place this formula?

Comment: OK, now sorted. Could you tell me how to use your expression for the decimal type?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the decimal type"*?

Comment: instead of "text string"

Comment: Can you please explain to me how would you like to have that *decimal type*, how will it look like?

Comment: I think, that I already solved my problem, as I can run the centroid expression, which makes a perfect shortcut.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374849/merging-attributes-of-selected-features-not-working-in-qgis-3

Thank you very much for the help. I will definitely take into account your option when working with geoJSON or sth.

Answer (score 5):

You may use the field calculator to add the coordinates of a feature to the attribute table. In cases like yours I usually create two fields, one for the X coordinate, and one for Y.

The expression is utterly simple:

```
$x
```

This writes the X coordinate in a column. The same goes for `$y`. Afterwards you can copy & paste the attribute table to excel.

You should choose the column type according to your CRS.

Comment: I suppose @Erik can refer to this thread [Exporting x,y coordinates as latitude,longitude](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364526/exporting-x-y-coordinates-as-latitude-longitude/)

Comment: Pay attention that when applying *copy & paste the attribute table* into Excel, it is not 100% sure whether Excel will maintain the type/format of the output data, I will suggest using one of solutions provided here [Exporting attribute table to Excel from QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135801/exporting-attribute-table-to-excel-from-qgis).

Comment: if I type $x it returns NULL. What am I missing?

Comment: `NULL` can appear when you use `$x` or `$y` for polylines and polygons

Comment: yes, exactly i've got the polygons. Shall I make it for the points only then?

Comment: yes, I think @Erik meant points in his answer

Comment: Oh that sucks. I have the polygons lines and polylines mostly. Is there any way to set the coordinates for polygons at least?

Comment: @MKR since you're talking about "all points from the given layer" I assumed you had points. My solution doesn't work for lines/polygons.

Comment: Ok thank you for clarification. I will definitely use it for points in the future.